# Out of gas & Exceeds block gas limit, but contract size <24KB

Tags: erc-20, gas-limit, openzeppelin, out-of-gas, voting

I've 2 contracts I'm trying to deploy on mainnet-fork, but I keep getting this error:

> VirtualMachineError: out of gas

When I try to increase the gas limit, I get this:

> ValueError: Exceeds block gas limit

When I deploy it on the Rinkeby network, I don't get this error, same for BSC testnet.
If I take the Bytecode from the deployed contract in Rinkeby I get around 23KB (<24.5KB limit), so it seems that the size should be fine right? Or does it change depending on the network?

Thanks for your help ;)

I couldn't implement RFI and Voting in the same contract as that would make it too big, so I had to separate it into 2 contracts

I'm woking with Brownie, this is my config file:
[pastebin.com/wDRsbPjV](https://pastebin.com/wDRsbPjV)

Comment: Which platform are you using for deployment (eg. Hardhat)? Can you add the config file you use for the various networks?

Comment: @KenzoAgada I added the config file at the end of my post. Thanks for helping!

Comment: I see. I haven't used Brownie but you probably need to increase your gas price and maybe gas limit. See here on how to do it. https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api-network.html . Eth mainnet requires much higher gas price than Rinkeby/BSC so this is probably the issue.